# Topologist's Comb

Tags: general-topology

I've already posted another question because I've got an assignment to finish (still got half a day left :/) and had to realise that I'm a bit lost.
Anyway, the question has to do with the following comb space:

$Y=\{(x,0):x\in[0,1]\}\cup\{(1/n,y):y\in[0,1],n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

I have to:

a) Draw it. (which is easy...)
b) Find a bijection from $[0,1]$ to Y.
c) Show that $[0,1]$ and Y are not homeomorphic.

I'm struggling with the bijection at the moment. Any help?

Cheers

Tom

Comment: So what have you done?

Comment: I've tried to do it like I would if I was to find a bijection between ,say, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$, that is by "mixing" decimal digits (loosely spoken). I must admit I've never actually done that proof in full but it would at least be good to know wheather I'm on the right track or not. Cheers

Comment: I think I have actually found a bijective mapping... finally. As for the homeomorphism, is it really as simple as saying that since $[0,1]$ is compact and Y is not (missing limit points)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion for the bijection.  Take the tooth of the comb at $x=\frac{1}{n}$, shrink it to a length of $\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$, and map it to the unit interval

$$\left[\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right]$$

Then shrink the open intervals $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ on the base of the comb to $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)})$.

Visually, we're shrinking each tooth and folding them onto the base, but we shrink each enough to be able to map the base into itself such that the base's image is the complement of the image of the teeth.

Make sense?

Also, a hint for the third part of the problem: Notice that the points $(0,a)$ are limit points of $Y$ for $a\in[0,1]$, but $(0,a)\in Y$ if and only if $a=0$.

Comment: thanks. I think I see what you mean. ure choosing smaller and smaller intervalls in $[0,1]$ and "fold" the shrunk teeth in there. however, maybe I made a mistake (it's quite late here already) but I think for $n=3$, the tooth lenght it 5/24 but the interval is only from 7/24 to 8/24...?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, you're right.  I miscalculated.  I've edited, as well as explained how to map the base of the comb.  For the third part, the compactness argument you gave is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the bijective mapping f:[0,1] to (0,1] defined by

f(a,b) = $\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{2} & : x=0\\
       \frac{1}{n+1} & : x=\frac{1}{n}\\
       x & : otherwise\\ 
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Now try and map the set $\{(x,0):x\in[0,1]\}$ to say [0,$\frac{1}{2}$) and then map $\{(1/n,y):y\in(0,1]\}$ for each fixed n to [$\frac{1}{n+1}$,$\frac{1}{n+2}$). This will give you a bijective function.

I have muddled it up a little, as I am in a hurry now but I think the gist is clear.